# How can I make bullets be vertically aligned on a unordered list?

Tags: html, css

How can I align all my bullets perfectly?

Expected result: Bullets line up to one another
Actual result: They move depending on how big the text is for the

JSFiddle for clarification:
https://jsfiddle.net/hk12hhp1/

Result I want (look at red line):
http://prntscr.com/grt24m (make bullets aligned just like red line is straight)

Fiddle code:

```
<div id='center-everything'>
<ul>
<li>test1wef</li>
<li>test2ferwfwergwerg</li>
<li>test3grew</li>
</ul>
</div>
#center-everything{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  height:  100px;
  width:  200px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

***Note: I still want text-align to be center***

Comment: the bullets are next to the text. if the text is centered, the bullets are next to the start of the text.

Comment: So do *really* want the text to be centered? With the bullets in a line down the left with gaps of varying between them and the text, because the text isn't in a nice neat line? Or are you really just trying to add a margin to the left of a left-aligned list in order to make the entire list *appear* centered in the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution, using pseudo-element to create the bullet, with `position: absolute` positioning it on the left.

```css
#center-everything {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

li:before {
  content: '☻';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 1px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id='center-everything'>
  <ul>
    <li>test1wef</li>
    <li>test2ferwfwergwerg</li>
    <li>test3grew</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't at all clear about exactly what you mean by wanting the bullets vertically aligned on a centered list.

Having the bullets all the way to the left in a centered list is not any sort of standard typography conventions, so I think you might really be asking is for the entire left-aligned list inside the container? I've seen this asked more often than having the bullets float all the way to the left.

```css
#center-everything {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0; /* remove any padding to stop it throwing off the "center" */
  margin: auto; /* center the ul */
  display: inline-block; /* hack to make the ul only as wide as its contents */
}
```

```html
<div id='center-everything'>
  <ul>
    <li>test1wef</li>
    <li>test2ferwfwergwerg</li>
    <li>test3grew</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

To do this, you just need to change the styling for the ul, nothing else.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted? The OP isn't clear about their exact requirements, so this is another way of interpreting them.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#center-everything{
  background-color: gray;
  height:  100px;
  width:  300px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li:before {
  content: "■"
}

span {
  position: absolute;
 left: 150px;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id='center-everything'>
<ul>
<li></li><span>test1wef</span><br>
<li></li><span>test2wef</span><br>
<li></li><span>test3wef</span><br>  
</ul>
</div>
```